# Which command do I use to login to a container with podman?

Tags: command-line, container, podman

I created a pod named multi-container. Its a `yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: multi-container
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-container
  - image: redis
    name: redis-container
  - image: consul
    name: consul-container
```

If I need to login to any of the container, what command do I use?

Comment: Is this for Podman?

Comment: In the pod, I had created 3 container. Now if i need to login to any of the container. what command i need to give.

Comment: Hi @santhosh This yaml looks much more like a POD specification for Kobernetes than for docker / podman. Please clarify your environment.

Comment: Yes please specify if this is a Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on Podman, but as far as I can see [from the documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-exec.1.html), the commands are the same as in Docker (since Podman is intended as a daemonless drop-in replacement for Docker).

The basic syntax for running a command inside a container is:

```
podman exec [options] [container-name] [command [args …]]
```

So if you want to run an interactive shell (login) in the `nginx-container`, you would use:

```
podman exec -ti nginx-container /bin/sh
```

Or a bash shell: (depends on the container if this exist)

```
podman exec -ti nginx-container /bin/bash
```

The `-ti` option attached a virtual console and starts an interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

The yaml looks like a part of an POD Specification for Kubernetes / Openshift / Minikube etc.

It can be deployed with

```
kubectl apply -f <FILENAME>
```

and generates a single POD with 3 Container.
for Login use the kubectl syntax

```
kubectl exec -it <PODNAME> -c <CONTAINERNAME> -- /bin/sh
```

`PODNAME` and `CONTAINERNAME` must be replaced with your Values.

This would look like

```
kubectl exec -it multi-container -c consul-container -- /bin/sh
```

If you use openshift you man use `oc` instead on `kubectl`.

`kubectl` is very well documented. see [Kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

Comment: You're probably right - but since the OP is not specifying what it is, it's hard to know unless you're very familiar with the syntax.